# Javascript not executed by pdfreactor

Tags: java, migration, pdf-generation, pdf-reactor

In my project I'm using pdfreactor for generating PDF from HTML file.

I migrated my project pdfreactor from java 8 -> 17

Everything is ok, except, code js (into my .html) doesnot executes.
(My script js add class attributes to any tag)

Is this security problem?

I enable JS in my config by :

```
setJavaScriptSettings(new Configuration.JavaScriptSettings().setEnabled(true));
```

but It does not works